# Minimization via eigendecomposition of Hadamard matrix products

Tags: optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $\boldsymbol{\mathcal{R}}$ and $\boldsymbol{\mathcal{M}}$ be $n\times n$ Hermitian matrices (which are known) and let $\boldsymbol{\mathcal{G}}$ be a rank one $n\times n$ (unknown) Hermitian matrix. Moreover, let $\odot$ represent the Hadamard product, $()^{\top}$ denote the Hadamard matrix inverse and $||~||_F$ denote the Frobenius norm.

Determine $\boldsymbol{\mathcal{G}}$ such that
$||\boldsymbol{\mathcal{R}}-\boldsymbol{\mathcal{M}}\odot\boldsymbol{\mathcal{G}}||_{F}$ is minimized. Can the above problem be solved by minimizing $||\boldsymbol{\mathcal{M}}^{\top}\odot\boldsymbol{\mathcal{R}}-\boldsymbol{\mathcal{G}}||_{F}$ with eigendecomposition? Will the $\boldsymbol{\mathcal{G}}$ that minimizes $||\boldsymbol{\mathcal{M}}^{\top}\odot\boldsymbol{\mathcal{R}}-\boldsymbol{\mathcal{G}}||_{F}$ also minimize $||\boldsymbol{\mathcal{R}}-\boldsymbol{\mathcal{M}}\odot\boldsymbol{\mathcal{G}}||_{F}$?